# I have problem with my JS. file when linking it with my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

So problem is that when I have script inside my html it works but when is in external file it doesn't work.
Please help me I cannot find correct answer.

-HTML-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/Algebra-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="/js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    <title>SUPIT</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#login" class="prijavi-se"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-sign-in"></i><span> Prijavi se</span></a>
        <a href="/index.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Početna</a>
        <a href="#onama"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> O nama</a>
        <a href="#novosti"><i class="fa fa-circle-info"></i> Novosti</a>
        <a href="#kontakt"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Kontakt</a>
      </div>
      
      <div class="video-container">
      <video src="video/typingOnlaptop.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
      <div class="video-text">
        <p id="typing"></p>
      </div>
      </div>

      
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  <script>
    
  const typingElement = document.getElementById("typing");
  const textArray = ["Welcome to my website!"]; 
  let arrayIndex = 0;
  let characterIndex = 0;

  function type(){
    if (characterIndex < textArray[arrayIndex].length) {
      typingElement.textContent += textArray[arrayIndex].charAt(characterIndex);
      characterIndex++;
    }; 
    setTimeout(type, 100);
    if (characterIndex === textArray[arrayIndex].length) {
      setTimeout();
    }
  }

  function erase() {
    if (characterIndex > 0) {
      typingElement.textContent = textArray[arrayIndex].substring(0, characterIndex - 1);
      characterIndex--;
    };

    setTimeout(erase, 50);
    if (characterIndex === 0) {
      arrayIndex++;
      if (arrayIndex >= textArray.length) {
        arrayIndex = 0;
      }
      setTimeout(type, 500);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(type, 1500); 

</script>

});
```

I tried with $(document).ready(function(){ code line but and everything else buit it doesnt wokrs.I am trying but i cannot solve it.

Comment: Have you used your browsers' dev tools inspect facility to see whether the css file is being found? (ie have you got the right address for it?)

Comment: you cant place `<script>` tags inside the js code, and `$(document)` is jquery which your not using, use `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {})`

Comment: there is no method named `<script>` or  `</script>` in JavaScript. **Check your browser console**.

Comment: Also, you need a better title for this post.

Comment: Perhaps a title that better distinguishes your problem so that other people can easily find this post to answer *their* quesiton.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In js with seperate file you cant add `<script>` tag. You should remove  `$(document).ready(function(){` and remove `<script>` tag. Just add your `app.js` before end of `</body>` tag.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/Algebra-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
  <title>SUPIT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#login" class="prijavi-se"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-sign-in"></i><span> Prijavi se</span></a>
    <a href="/index.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Početna</a>
    <a href="#onama"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> O nama</a>
    <a href="#novosti"><i class="fa fa-circle-info"></i> Novosti</a>
    <a href="#kontakt"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Kontakt</a>
  </div>

  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="video/typingOnlaptop.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    <div class="video-text">
      <p id="typing"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="/js/app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
const typingElement = document.getElementById("typing");
const textArray = ["Welcome to my website!"];
let arrayIndex = 0;
let characterIndex = 0;

function type() {
  if (characterIndex < textArray[arrayIndex].length) {
    typingElement.textContent += textArray[arrayIndex].charAt(characterIndex);
    characterIndex++;
  }
  setTimeout(type, 100);
  if (characterIndex === textArray[arrayIndex].length) {
    setTimeout();
  }
}

function erase() {
  if (characterIndex > 0) {
    typingElement.textContent = textArray[arrayIndex].substring(
      0,
      characterIndex - 1
    );
    characterIndex--;
  }

  setTimeout(erase, 50);
  if (characterIndex === 0) {
    arrayIndex++;
    if (arrayIndex >= textArray.length) {
      arrayIndex = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(type, 500);
  }
}
setTimeout(type, 1500);
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a  tag in the JS. Delete the script tags in the JS file, and it will work (unless there's an issue somewhere else in the code, too)

Comment: Isn't that what the other answer already says? No need to say it again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link your javascript file to your html file you should use
`script` tag inside the body of your html tag. The src you should use in your code should be the name of your file:`<script srs="script.js"></script>`. this is the full code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/Algebra-logo.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
  <title>SUPIT</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a href="#login" class="prijavi-se"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-sign-in"></i><span> Prijavi se</span></a>
    <a href="/index.html"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Početna</a>
    <a href="#onama"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i> O nama</a>
    <a href="#novosti"><i class="fa fa-circle-info"></i> Novosti</a>
    <a href="#kontakt"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Kontakt</a>
  </div>

  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="video/typingOnlaptop.mp4" autoplay loop></video>
    <div class="video-text">
      <p id="typing"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

And you should remove the `script` tags from your code because it will cause an error.
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

`defer` makes the script run once the document is done loading:

```
<script defer src="/js/app.js"></script>
```